# LeetCode: Diameter of Binary Tree

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, tree

https://leetcode.com/problems/diameter-of-binary-tree/

> Given a binary tree, you need to compute the length of the diameter of
>   the tree. The diameter of a binary tree is the length of the longest
>   path between any two nodes in a tree. This path may or may not pass
>   through the root.
>
> ```
> Example:
> Given a binary tree
>           1
>          / \
>         2   3
>        / \     
>       4   5
> ```
>
> Return 3, which is the length of the path [4,2,1,3] or [5,2,1,3].
>
> Note: The length of path between two nodes is represented by the
>   number of edges between them.

```
 [TestClass]
    public class DiameterOfBinaryTreeTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DiameterOfBinaryTreeTest1()
        {
                        /* Constructed binary tree is
                       1
                     /   \
                   2      3
                 /  \
               4     5
             */
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);
            root.left = new TreeNode(2);
            root.left.left = new TreeNode(4);
            root.left.right = new TreeNode(5);
            root.right = new TreeNode(3);
            DiameterOfBinaryTreeClass diam = new DiameterOfBinaryTreeClass();

            int result = diam.DiameterOfBinaryTree(root);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
        }
}



 //https://leetcode.com/problems/diameter-of-binary-tree/
    public class DiameterOfBinaryTreeClass
    {
        public int DiameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int leftDiameter = DiameterOfBinaryTree(root.left);
            int rightDiameter = DiameterOfBinaryTree(root.right);

            int leftHeight = Height(root.left);
            int rightHeight = Height(root.right);
            return Math.Max(leftHeight + rightHeight, Math.Max(leftDiameter,rightDiameter));
        }

        private int Height(TreeNode root)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return Math.Max(Height(root.left) ,Height(root.right)) + 1;
        }
    }
```

Please review for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method visits mosts nodes *twice:* Here

```
int leftDiameter = DiameterOfBinaryTree(root.left);
int rightDiameter = DiameterOfBinaryTree(root.right);

int leftHeight = Height(root.left);
int rightHeight = Height(root.right);
```

calling `DiameterOfBinaryTree` on the left and right subtree determines the height of both subtrees, and then calling `Height` on the subtrees computes those heights again.

This can be improved by defining a helper function which (recursively) computes *both* height and diameter of a tree rooted at a node:

```
private (int height, int diam) HeightAndDiameter(TreeNode root)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        return (0, 0);
    }

    var (leftHeight, leftDiam) = HeightAndDiameter(root.left);
    var (rightHeight, rightDiam) = HeightAndDiameter(root.right);

    return (Math.Max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1,
            Math.Max(Math.Max(leftDiam, rightDiam), leftHeight + rightHeight));
}
```

C# *(named) tuples* are used here to return both values to the caller. The main function then becomes

```
public int DiameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root)
{
    return HeightAndDiameter(root).diam;
}
```

Each node is visited exactly once now.

Answer (score 1):

According to letcode submissions tab:

```
                                        Runtime   Memory
Original solution form the question      108 ms    25   MB
Solution from this answer (no recursion) 104 ms    26   MB
Solution form Martin R answer            100 ms    25.3 MB
Solution from this answer (recursive)     84 ms    24.7 MB
```

**Solution recursive**

```
public class DiameterOfBinaryTreeClass
    {
        private int MaxD = 0;

        public int DiameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root)
        {
            Height(root);
            return MaxD;
        }

        private int Height(TreeNode root)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int l = Height(root.left);
            int r = Height(root.right);
            int d = l + r;
            if (d > MaxD)
                MaxD = d;

            return Math.Max(l, r) + 1;
        }
    }
```

**No recursion solution:**

```
private int MaxD = 0;

public int DiameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
 Solve(root);
 return MaxD;
}

class CalcNode {
 public sbyte Direction;
 public int Left;
 public int Right;
 public TreeNode TreeNode;
}

private void Solve(TreeNode root) {
 if (root == null)
  return;

 var stack = new Stack < CalcNode > ();

 stack.Push(new CalcNode() {
  Direction = 0, Left = 0, Right = 0, TreeNode = root
 });
 HashSet < TreeNode > usedTreeNodes = new HashSet < TreeNode > ();

 while (stack.Count != 0) {
  TreeNode cur = stack.Peek().TreeNode;
  if (cur.left != null && !usedTreeNodes.Contains(cur.left)) {
   stack.Push(new CalcNode() {
    Direction = -1, Left = 0, Right = 0, TreeNode = cur.left
   });
   continue;
  }

  if (cur.right != null && !usedTreeNodes.Contains(cur.right)) {
   stack.Push(new CalcNode() {
    Direction = 1, Left = 0, Right = 0, TreeNode = cur.right
   });
   continue;
  }

  CalcNode removedNode = stack.Pop();
  usedTreeNodes.Add(removedNode.TreeNode);
  int d = removedNode.Left + removedNode.Right;
  if (d > MaxD)
   MaxD = d;

  if (removedNode.Direction == 0)
   continue;

  CalcNode curCalcNode = stack.Peek();
  int removedNodeHeight = Math.Max(removedNode.Left, removedNode.Right) + 1;
  if (removedNode.Direction == 1)
   curCalcNode.Right += removedNodeHeight;
  else
   curCalcNode.Left += removedNodeHeight;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe, generally iteration is preferred over recursion. Can you show that/if iteration is feasible?

Comment: the code would be more complex, but the question was about peformance (not about a code simplisity) sure i can provide an example. Will do it in the next few days.

Comment: @JAD i decided to write recursive version first. With the next update I will unfold the recursion - it would be interesting to see the performance impact :)

Comment: My not recursive solution turned out to be slower as the recursive version